How to delete last character of text node from div element which has span as sibling
<div id="textarea">
abcd
<span id="cursor"></span>
</div>

How to delete character 'd' from the div tag using javascript or jquery ?

The last character is a newline. Use .trim() to remove the newline so you can work with just the text.

The span has nothing to do with this.

This question is similar to: How to get the text node of an element?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@JSONDerulo None of those answers say how to get and remove the last character, ignoring whitespace. How do you think it's similar?

With plain JavaScript this may be easier, as jQuery is not very powerful on working with text nodes.
You can get the targeted text node by first selecting the <span> element, and then taking the previousSibling property.
In below snippet I have added text after the cursor, and styled the cursor as a red vertical bar:


const node = document.querySelector("#cursor").previousSibling;
node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(/\S(\s*)$/, "$1");
#cursor { border-right: 2px solid red }
<div>
  abcd
  <span id="cursor"></span>
  rest
</div>



Note that this does not touch the <span> itself, or any other sibling elements, nor does this solution make assumptions about the presence of other siblings. It only expects that the <span> element is preceded by a text node that needs to lose its last non-white space character.
Secondly, it doesn't remove the trailing white-space characters (if any). If removed, it might render the <span> closer to the text than intended. To keep that white-space untouched, a regular expression is used to identify the last non-white space character, and it only removes that one character.

Note to anyone looking at this versus the other answer, this one is superior as it deals with a more general case (and doesn't need jquery).

You can remove the last char from the div using this mathod
var $div = $("#textarea");
var text = $div.text().trim();

if (text.length > 0) {
  text = text.slice(0, -1); 
}

$div.html(text + '<span id="cursor"></span>');


They don't want to remove any d, they specifically asked how to remove the last character. It's just a d in this example.

Got it and updated my Answer

Be aware that by setting the HTML of $div you lose any other elements that might have been present in that div, and the span will lose any event handlers that might have been attached to it. Also, if the text had any HTML entities in it, those will be interpreted as such, which will change a literal &lt; to <, ...etc.
